# Given the time in hh:mm:ss format, compute the number of seconds using base R

Tags: r, time, lapply, posixct

I have a `character` object with the time in `hh:mm:ss`-like format.

A given vector `a` for example purposes:

```
[1] "01|15|59" "1|47|16"  "01|17|20" "1|32|34"  "2|17|17"
```

I want to compute the number of seconds for each measurement.

For the first one you can simply do:

```
a <-  as.numeric(strsplit(a, "|", fixed=TRUE)[[1]])
a[1]*60*60 + a[2]*60 + a[3]
```

I could use a loop to iterate through all of the elements of the `char` object, but ideally I would like to use an `apply` function. Not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sapply()`:

```r
sapply(strsplit(a, "\\|"), \(x) sum(as.numeric(x) * 60^(2:0)))
# [1] 4559 6436 4640 5554 8237
```

or convert the time string to `POSIXct` and pass it to `as.numeric()` to get seconds:

```r
as.numeric(strptime(paste('1970-01-01', a), '%F %H|%M|%S', 'UTC'))
# [1] 4559 6436 4640 5554 8237
```

```r
difftime(strptime(a, '%H|%M|%S', 'UTC'), Sys.Date(), units = 'sec')
# Time differences in secs
# [1] 4559 6436 4640 5554 8237
```

---

###### Data

```r
a <- c("01|15|59", "1|47|16", "01|17|20", "1|32|34", "2|17|17")
```

Comment: Thank you @Darren Tsai,what is exactly the purpose of `\(x)` in the first method

Comment: @DawitZuri `\(x)` is a shortcut of `function(x)`. This was born in the newer R version.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the `|` (vertical bar) needs to be escaped in your `strsplit()`. Otherwise it acts as a logical "or", resulting in a split on each character. Use `[|]` or `\\|`.

With a list object created by `a <- strsplit(a, '[|]')` You as could extract each list element with the `` `[[` `` function within `sapply()`. For example:

```
#Splits your vector on vertical pipe, with list output
a <- strsplit(a, '[|]')
#Apply extract function across list  
3600*as.numeric( sapply(a,`[[`,1)) +
60*as.numeric( sapply(a,`[[`,2))+
as.numeric( sapply(a,`[[`,3))
[1] 4559 6436 4640 5554 8237
```